# Grails : send value from controller to view

Tags: grails

I'm new for `grails` and I've been trying some tutorial but it's not working. I want to

pass value to the view but it's empty. My code is as following:

Controller:

```
package grail.test.project

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(HelloController)
class HelloControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def index() {
        render(model:[name : "JOHNY"])
     }
}
```

View (views/hello/index.jsp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <title>Welcome to Grails</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World !!! This is grails application for testing project with text.
        <br>
        Parameter from controller: ${name}
    </body>
</html>
```

It's not print the name that send from controller. I might miss something, please help thank you.

Comment: Your controller file name is wrong. This is spock test case , It is not controller. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using render method in test case that is not possible. Please create your controller like .

```
class HelloController {

    def index() {
        render(view:'index',model:[name : "JOHNY"])
     }
}
```

Comment: When I create new controller, it always generate something like I posted. I can't create controller like your post.

Comment: It is generate both Spec and main controller . You can search in controller directory . It is test case that generate with controller.

Comment: Ahhh I got it. I'm such an idiot. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are using intellij ide you can search your controller file using ctrl + shift +N.

Comment: You could replace `render(view:'index',model:[name : "JOHNY"])` with `[name : "JOHNY"]`.

Answer (score 1):

As I saw, you have problem in syntax for render(), either you have to write

```
render(view:'index',model:[name : "JOHNY"])
```

or just

```
[name:"JOHNY"]
```